# How to import the IIFE version of a module?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-frontend

I have a react/next project. I'm trying to `import '@solidity/parser'`

this module has cjs (node) version and iife (browser) version.

whenever I use `import '@solidity/parser'` I am getting an error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'` (yes it's looking for a module named 'module')

since the browser is loading `node_modules/@solidity-parser/parser/dist/index.cjs.js` but whereas I need `node_modules/@solidity-parser/parser/dist/index.iife.js` (**iife** instead of **cjs**)

the **iife** version works when I use a script tag, but then I don't see the type information from the module. is there a way to choose iife version, or alternatively I could use a script tag but how do I import the type information without getting this error?